# how to custom a loss function with multiple inputs and outputs?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm simulating a simple CNN model with two input sets (MNIST and its noise version), namely `x_r` and `x_p`. The corresponding outputs are represented by `y_r` and `y_p`. The loss function of this model is composed of three parts `E_R(x_r, y_r)`, `E_P(x_p, y_p)` and `mse(x_r, x_p)`. How can I write codes of loss funtion with tensorflow or keras?

The structure of the CNN model is shown as follows.

```py
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')
maxpool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')
maxpool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
flatten = Flatten()
dense1 = Dense(1024, activation='tanh')
dropout = Dropout(0.5)
dense2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')
```

I train the model with two inputs: MNIST `x_r` and processed MNIST (add noise) `x_p`

```py
X_r = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28, 1))
Y_r = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 10))
X_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28, 1))
Y_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 10))

conv1_in1 = conv1(X_r)
conv1_in2 = conv1(X_p)
maxpool1_in1 = maxpool1(conv1_in1)
maxpool1_in2 = maxpool1(conv1_in2)
conv2_in1 = conv2(maxpool1_in1)
conv2_in2 = conv2(maxpool1_in2)
maxpool2_in1 = maxpool2(conv2_in1)
maxpool2_in2 = maxpool2(conv2_in2)
flatten_in1 = flatten(maxpool2_in1)
flatten_in2 = flatten(maxpool2_in2)
dense1_in1 = dense1(flatten_in1)
dense1_in2 = dense1(flatten_in2)
dropout_in1 = tf.nn.dropout(dense1_in1, 0.5)
dropout_in2 = tf.nn.dropout(dense1_in2, 0.5)
output1 = dense2(dropout_in1)
output2 = dense2(dropout_in2)
```

I design the loss function as (TODO)

```py
# custom loss
alpha = 1.
beta = 1.
gama = 0.01
loss_r = alpha * tf.reduce_mean(np.sum(Y_r * tf.nn.softmax(output1), -1))
loss_p = beta * tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=output2, labels=Y_p))
loss_d = gama * tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(X_r, X_p))
total_loss = loss_p+loss_p#+loss_d

optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1,momentum=0.9).minimize(total_loss)
```

`loss_d` has been commented because it cannot be added with `loss_r` and `lodd_p`.

As I said, the custom loss is the sum of `E_R(x_r, y_r)`, `E_P(x_p, y_p)` and `mse(x_r, x_p)`, so how should I implement the loss function, especially for the third term `mse(x_r, x_p)`?

Comment: https://github.com/MrDongdongLin/piracyDNN/blob/master/train_fixed.ipynb